# Vuejs Vuex component not updated when store change

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I want to activate / desactivate a simple spinner.

I've create a store to handle the state of the spinner :

```
const spinnerStore = {
  state: {
    isActive: false
  },

  mutations: {
    startSpinner: function (state) {
      console.log('start');
      state.isActive = true
    },

    stopSpinner: function (state) {
      console.log('stop');
      state.isActive = false
    }
  },

  actions: {
    startSpinner: function ({commit}) {
      commit('startSpinner');
    },

    stopSpinner: function ({commit}) {
      commit('stopSpinner');
    }
  }
}

const store = new Vuex.Store({
    modules: {
        'mapEditor': mapEditorStore,
        'spinner': spinnerStore
    }
});
```

And I create a Vue to handle the view.

```
<script type="x-template" id="vueSpinnerTemplate">
  <div class="mdl-spinner mdl-js-spinner mdl-spinner--single-color" style="position: absolute; bottom: 50px; right: 50px; z-index: 10" v-bind:class="{'is-active': isActive}"> </div>
</script>

<script>

var vm = new Vue({

    store,

    template: '#vueSpinnerTemplate',

    computed: {
        isActive: function () {
            console.log('called');
            return this.$store.state.spinner.isActive
        }
    }
}).$mount('#spinner-mount-point');

</script>
```

Vue.use(Vuex) is called somewhere because I have this message when I try this line :

`[vuex] already installed. Vue.use(Vuex) should be called only once.`

If I set in the store the default value to `true` I see my spinner so the html/template is ok.

In my code, I use Jquery to make an async request, and I want my spinner to show up so I use :

```
store.dispatch('startSpinner');
$.ajax({
  url : "myUrl", 
  success: function (data) {
      store.dispatch('stopSpinner'); 
  }
});
```

Unfortanutelly, I can't see the spinner showing up. (My request takes 2 secondes)

So I looked in the console and I see :

called
start
stop
called

That mean that the component didn't call isActive between start and stop.

How to fix that

Thanks

Edit: I've a beggining of solution.

My ajax request is synchrone. I think it block the component to render or something like that... When I put `async: true` can see the spinner

Comment: I don't see a `Vue.use(Vuex)` anywhere in your code and you're not creating a Vuex store (`new Vuex.Store`) -- you're just creating a shared state variable.

Comment: I didn't put all the code in post, see my edit :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not absolutely sure if it's the problem but I would try to create a getter for the "isActive".
It would usually look like that then:

```
return this.$store.getters.spinnerIsActive
```

I am not actually sure how creating a constant works in vuex so it might be also something like this

```
return this.$store.getters.spinner.spinnerIsActive
```

or

```
return this.$store.spinner.getters.spinnerIsActive
```

Getters look like this:

```
getters = {
    spinnerIsActive: state => state.isActive
}
```

You can also check how i've built the [store in my project](https://github.com/KeepCUBE/KeepCUBE-WebUI-NG/tree/develop/resources/assets/js/store). It's not that complex at all and it might be helpful. Btw, it doesn't probably solve your problem, but notice that usual `delete` doesn't trigger an event so Vue.delete() needs to be used in [here](https://github.com/KeepCUBE/KeepCUBE-WebUI-NG/blob/develop/resources/assets/js/store/modules/devices.js#L58).